# Convert native swift Set into array

Tags: swift

I need to convert a Set into an array of either [AnyObject] or [String] is this possible? I know with an NSSet I can use .allObjects but there doesn't seem to be any functions for this with a native set

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Just coerce directly to an Array:

```
let arr = Array(mySet)
```

Comment: And see my Swift book: http://www.apeth.com/swiftBook/ch04.html#_set